# Intuitive interpretation of the covariance matrix

Tags: covariance-matrix, intuition

I am trying to get a "feel" for the covariance matrix. I know that $v_iCov(X)v_j$ gives the covariance between $X$ projected along $v_i$ and $v_j$. I'm curious if there's a similar intuitive interpretation of $Cov(X)v$ for any vector $v$.

Edit:

$X$ is a vector of $n$ random variables and $v_i, v_j, v \in R^n$

Comment: A good linear algebra textbook will provide helpful explanations of dual spaces, which is the underlying fundamental concept here.

Comment: "Covariance is the difference between the average product and the product of averages"

Comment: @whuber that's really interesting can you point to any source? I have learned about dual spaces but I don't know how they relate.

Comment: Mervyn Stone (1987), "Coordinate-Free Multivariable Statistics", Clarendon Press, Oxford.  Michael Wichura (2006), "The Coordinate-Free Approach to Linear Models," Cambridge Univ. Press.